# Getting facebook's JSON?

Tags: facebook, json

I need a little help with getting some JSON out of facebook, basically all I need to do is get the status text and post it to a website.

I'm using the method below, but the access_tokens with this method expires every hour.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/SOME_ID?fields=statuses.limit(10).fields(message)&access_token=SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN', function(data) {});
```

Note that i got the URL above from facebook graph API explorer.

any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

***update:***

I used FB.api, but i'm not sure if I've done it correctly as it is sending me this error 
"An access token is required to request this resource."

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'My_app_id', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//myHost.com/facebook/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.api('USER_ID?fields=statuses.fields(message)', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

Note that i replaced (my_app_id, myHost.com and USER_ID) with the right values.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer is helpful - mark it "accepted". This will close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user needs to be logged in to Facebook and allow your app before you can call the API, update your code to this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'My_app_id', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//myHost.com/facebook/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('USER_ID?fields=statuses.fields(message)', function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
  };
```

More information on the getLoginStatus status: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

You will also need to also need to ask the permission user_status see the doc for more details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

You should ask for permissions when calling FB.login:

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'user_status'});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Thanks Gabriel,

This solution is for facebook users, What I need is to grab the JSON and post it on my website as lets say "my latest facebook status", just like twitter feed.

makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the Javascript SDK implemented i would suggest using the FB.api method.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Comment: I used fb.api, but it is giving me this error ""An access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: Have you asked for the correct permissions when you logged in?https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ To log in you user using Javascript see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Use the FB.api method after you have logged your user in. Ie not in the initialization of the JS SDK.

Comment: @Rob If the answer is helpful - mark it "accepted". This will close the question and add 2 points to your reputation.